# Ios Iterate on IBOutletCollection TextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, iboutletcollection

I'm trying to iterate and show my array on my text view collection.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITextView) NSArray *myTextViewCollection;`

But on the UI, only the last element in my array is available.

I iterate with :

```
    for (UITextView *textView in myTextViewCollection) {
        for (int i = 0; i < feeds.count; i++) {
           textView.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
           textView.editable = false;
        }
     }
```

`feeds` is a NSMutableArray contening a list of NSMutableDictionnary object.

An idea ?

Comment: Where is the "i" variable coming from?

Comment: I've edit my question to add the i variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myTextViewCollection.count; i++) {
    UITextView * textView = myTextViewCollection[i];
    textView.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
    textView.editable = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you nslogged 'feeds' to make sure it contains the correct values?

Comment: If feeds & myTextViewCollection are both set properly, this should work.  Every answer submitted so far is correct in solving your initial problem.  If there is still an error, it is something else.

Comment: Ok, the problem is maybe about the myTextViewCollection ? How to initialize it ? The for loop just do one iteration

Comment: Have you used a break point to single-step through the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;
for (UITextView *textView in myTextViewCollection) {
     textView.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:i++] objectForKey:@"title"];
     textView.editable = false;
 }
```

Comment: I've tested, this action show only one element of my array too

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
for (UITextView *textView in myTextViewCollection) {
    for (int i = 0; i < feeds.count; i++) {
       textView.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
       textView.editable = false;
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (UITextView *textView in myTextViewCollection) {
   textView.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:feeds.count - 1] objectForKey:@"title"];
   textView.editable = false;
}
```

this is the reason why only the last element array is shown.

You should change code to something like

```
int i = 0;
for (UITextView *textView in myTextViewCollection) {
    textView.text = feeds[i++][@"title"];
    textView.editable = false;
}
```

Comment: I've tested too this solution ... But same result than the initial context